# MySQL manipulation

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a site with Persian data.

I need to get a count of just the first names as they appear in the db

---

This is what I've used

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(books2.Author2), ' ', -1) as authorsname, COUNT(*) as count FROM books2 GROUP BY authorsname ORDER BY count DESC;
```

to get a list of just first names and a count

So my author may be - "بهمن جلالي"

but I just want the last word fragment  "بهمن"

and the a count of the first names. I believe the above should do this.

---

Also the db is in bad shape with no index.

So I need to get the string value id from the sitelink column

"http://www.example.com/book.aspx?bookid=4"

to then populate a column called id

I'm not sure though how to do the join to properly run a SELECT id from books2 JOIN instert justidfrombooksource into id.

---

made it clearer

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td><td>SOURCELINK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> </td><td>www.example.com?book=1</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> </td><td>www.example.com?book=34</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I need to run a query that will UPDATE TO THIS

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td><td>SOURCELINK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>www.example.com?book=1</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>34</td><td>www.example.com?book=34</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What do I do - I've tried making a php script - that does this - but it times out/memory allocation issues.

SELECT id, sourcelink FROM books;

and then

something like

SELECT id, sourcelink FROM books

UPDATE books
SET id=1
WHERE sourcelink ='www.example.com?book=1';

Comment: I`ve read that twice,still dont know what you want.

Comment: Just guessing here... but Farsi reads (meaning: is FORMATTED FOR DISPLAY, not REPRESENTED IN MEMORY) right-to-left, meaning that what you're calling the "last word fragment" is in the *first* characters of your string, so I'm thinking that `REVERSE()` isn't going to work as intended.

Comment: What do you propose?

Comment: How would I do run a SELECT and UPDATE at the same time. I got a table of "books" but it doesn't have an ID column, I've made one. I need to SELECT - loop through the table, perform some pattern recogition on the SOURCELINK coloumn with a url with the bookid - to get just the ID, then UPDATE the id coloumn on the fly with just the number.